# Can this Regex be improved?

Tags: regex, c#-3.0

I have a regex to match a user entered id which has the basic format of `[a-zA-z]{2}[\d]{8}` but the kicker is a space can be placed between any of the letters or digits in the id so my regex looks like this

```
[A-Za-z]+[\s]*[A-Za-z]+[\s]*[\d]+[\s]*[\d]+[\s]*[\d]+[\s]*[\d]+[\s]*[\d]+[\s]*[\d]+[\s]*[\d]+[\s]*[\d]+[\s]*
```

Which is obviously an abomination and should be killed with fire, can this be improved upon?

All of the following are valid inputs

```
a b 1 2 2 3 4 5 5 6
ab12345678
ab 12345678
```

Comment: The best way to improve it is to stop making it ASCII-only.  ASCII is dead.  Don’t write ASCII-only regexes.

Comment: @tchrist: ASCII is not dead; there are a wide variety of applications where non-ASCII characters are definitely not expected, and that is very intentional. Mindless preaching without context isn't useful.

Comment: @Amber: I strongly disagree. If it is purely ASCII data, a Unicode-compliant regex will behave no differently on the ASCII. Adding Unicode-compliance does nothing to an ASCII regex apart from increasingly readability, expressivity, flexibility and maintainability.  But an ASCII-only regex will break on Unicode data.  There’s no reason to write ASCII-only regexes when you aren’t conforming to an RFC that includes specific octets.

Comment: Mind sharing some info instead of spouting death to ascii? In my case all data will be ASCII only but you could help future readers instead of just lifting your torch and pitchfork to chase out the ASCII regex users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex does not comply with your specification, can there be 2 or more letters before the digits? Extactly 8 digits or 8 digist or more?

Try

```
([a-zA-Z]\s*){2}(\d\s*){8}
```

If there can only be one space between each character:

```
([a-zA-Z]\s?){2}(\d\s?){8}
```

Comment: This is what I just came up with and just what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Don't ever use `\d` and `\s` unless you know EXACTLY where you are going...

`\d` will match 09E6 ০ BENGALI DIGIT ZERO (the ০ is your digit :-) ). For example read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1c0s6bb.aspx

`\s` will match more types of strange spaces (and the tab character) than you can count, and I'm not kidding. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx.aspx

Paradoxically using [a-zA-Z] you are limiting quite much your users... No àèéìòù, nor the Turkish ı and İ (the first one is an i without the dot, lower case, the second one is the upper case version of i) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I .
Perhaps you could use `(\p{L}\p{M}*)` (with brackets) instead of `[A-Za-z]` (all the letters plus the combining marks). You have to add an * or a + AFTER the close bracket. The one expression is for a single letter PLUS its combining marks.

Oh... and you can use one of the other suggestions as a basis for the regex :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
[\s]*[\d]+[\s]*[\d]+[\s]*[\d]+[\s]*[\d]+[\s]*[\d]+[\s]*[\d]+[\s]*[\d]+[\s]*[\d]+[\s]*
```

can be replaced with...

```
\s*(?:\d+\s*){8}
```

(Also, you can just write `\s`, rather than `[\s]`, and `\d` rather than `[\d]` - the brackets are redundant if you're only specifying a single backslash character class.)

**Edit** Since there seems to be some confusion about what part of the original regex is being replaced, here's the entire expression after replacement:

```
[A-Za-z]+\s*[A-Za-z]+\s*(?:\d+\s*){8}
```

Comment: also note the `[a-zA-Z]` for two characters at the beginning

Comment: It works for me using that exact same site... try again? Note that the part I said could be replaced is *not* the entire original expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:[A-Za-z]+\s*){2}(?:\d+\s*){8}
```